# Delete modems on OS X from the terminal

Tags: networking, macos, modem

I attached a dodgy Android device to my Mac, which evidently has caused it to install literally one thousand dialup devices.

[image: Screenshot of dialup device]

This is the detail of one such dialup device.

Here they appear in the Network screen of System Preferences, which has caused the screen to indeed to constantly lock up. I imagine it hasn't been designed for such abuse.

[image: Screenshot of Network preferences]

Unfortunately it takes quite some time to delete them one at a time as the screen is so unresponsive. Is there a way to delete them from the terminal in bulk?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently and the solution is very simple.

This file contains all network adapters:

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

I used "MT65x" on command because is the only visible part of your modem name from the picture. On picture says "MT65x...ader XXX", where XXX is a modem number. You can ignore and use only "MT65x" or replace with the complete name, removing the XXX number at end.

This command list all MT65x modems:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices | grep "MT65x"
```

This command removes one MT65x modem (where N is a modem number, ex: `MT65x 123`:

```
networksetup -deletepppoeservice "MT65x"`
```

To remove all MT65x Modems do it on terminal:

```
for service in $(/usr/sbin/networksetup -listallnetworkservices | grep "MT65x" ); do
    /usr/sbin/networksetup -deletepppoeservice "${service}"
done
```

Comment: dialup connections does not appear on the list of network services. Is there an alternative?